# Filtering in Linq in MVC4

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

My table structure is as follows

**Course**

```
ID    CourseName     

1       PHP
2       WORDPRESS
```

**MainCourse**

```
ID     MainCourseName
1       FoundationPhp
2       FoundationWordPress
3       Diploma
```

**SubCourse**

```
ID       MainCourseID   CourseID
 1           1             1
 2           2             2
 3           3             1
 3           3             2
```

I have a search scenario which should fetch the below result

When an user searches by `PHP` alone,he should get the following result

```
 MainCourseName    CourseCombination    
  FoundationPHP       PHP
  Diploma             PHP,WORDPRESS
```

When an user searches by `WORDPRESS` alone,he should get the following result

```
  MainCourseName           CourseCombination    
  FoundationWordPress       WORDPRESS
  Diploma                   PHP,WORDPRESS
```

When an user searches by `PHP,WORDPRESS` ,he should get the following result.

```
   MainCourseName           CourseCombination
    Diploma                    PHP,WORDPRESS
```

NOTE:If there is any other combination that contains both `PHP & WORDPRESS` that should be shown as well.Example of one such combination will be like `PHP,WORDPRESS,JAVA`.

I have tried the following method

```
     List<int> CourseId={1,2}//means user searches by both PHP & WORDPRESS
     var courseList = _db.SubCourses
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(mcd => courseId.Contains(mcd.Course.Id))
                      .Select(mc => new RegistraionVM.clsCourseCodeSearch
                       {
                          CourseCode = mc.MainCourse.MainCourseName,
                          CourseCombination = string.Join(",", mc.MainCourse.SubCourse
                                                                .Select(mcd => mcd.Course.Name))                     

                        }).Distinct().Take(5).ToList();
```

The above query returns the following result

```
  MainCourseName        CourseCombination    
  FoundationPHP         PHP
  FoundationWordPress   WORDPRESS
  Diploma               PHP,WORDPRESS
```

Desired result is

```
  MainCourseName        CourseCombination        
  Diploma               PHP,WORDPRESS
```

How can I acheive the above result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first groupby the `MainCourseID`, then use an `.All()` clause to select only items where all the resulting subcourses are included in the filter

```
var filter = new int[] { 1 }; // or new int[] { 1, 2 } etc

var results = list.GroupBy(x => x.MainCourseID).Select(x => new
{
    MainCourse = x.FirstOrDefault().MainCourse,
    SubCourseIDs = x.Select(y => y.Course.ID),
    SubCourseNames = x.Select(y => y.Course.CourseName)
}).Where(x => filter.All(y => x.SubCourseIDs.Contains(y))).Select(x => new RegistraionVM.clsCourseCodeSearch()
{
    CourseCode = x.MainCourse.MainCourseName,
    CourseCombination = String.Join(", ", x.SubCourseNames)
}).Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: This answer, as it is will only return the `ID` values, not the names as its not clear what the view model is that your projecting the results into - e.g. if the filter is `{ 1, 2 }` then the result will be `MainCourseName: 3, CourseCombination: "1, 2"`. I can fix it to display the names once your happy this returns the values you expect.

Comment: Yeaaah......Got the answer right mate.If possible please fix it to display names..

Comment: Have updated the answer. If I have interpreted you models correctly it should now give you `CourseCode: "Diploma", CourseCombination: "PHP, WORDPRESS"` if the filter is `{ 1, 2 }`

Comment: If possible kindly look into this question [Gapless Invoicenumber creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38244666/sequentialgapless-invoice-number-creation)

Comment: @ksg, I tend to agree with Scott Chamberlain's comments. If you want to create the number, do it in a trigger, but only associated with the INSERT operation. Although I don't understand why they need to be sequential - they should just be unique. And you going to run into problems if an invoice is ever deleted.

Comment: ,Thanks fo your comments and i'll try as you said.And regarding sequential part, Yes my customer wants the invoice number to be unique and sequential otherwise they could run into legal issues

Comment: I also have a small concern.What happens if multiple users click invoice button at the same time?Is there a chance for non sequential invoice number when we use trigger?

Answer (score -1):

PHP = 1
And MainCourse 1 and 3 have Course PHP = 1
so it should say:

FoundationPhp PHP
Diploma PHP,WORDPRESS

Or else I dont understand your question.

Comment: Yes Exactly,But if user searches by `PHP,WORDPRESS` then combination of the two courses should only be the result.`Foundation PHP` & `Foundation WORDPRESS` wont come.