# Sequential(Gapless) Invoice Number Creation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, concurrency, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

We have implemented a webapplication for Billing system.I have a string column to store invoice number. This column has to forbid gap between number.

```
  Id     InvoiceNumber(Desired)    InvoiceNumber(Actual)
   1         001                        001
   2         002                        002
   3         003                        005
```

*In pseudo-code*

```
using (TransactionScope _ts = new TransactionScope())
{

     var _lastGeneratedRecDetails = _db.StudentReceipts
                                            .Where(r => r.Status == true
                                                     && r.StudentRegistration.StudentWalkInn.CenterCode.Id == _centreCodeId
                                                     && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DueDate.Value) >= _startDate.Date
                                                     && EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(r.DueDate.Value) <= _endDate.Date)
                                            .AsEnumerable()
                                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReceiptNo != null ? Int32.Parse(x.ReceiptNo) : 0)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();

       var _newReceiptNo=Convert.ToInt32(_lastGeneratedRecDetails.ReceiptNo) + 1
     ....
     ....
     _ts.complete();

}
```

**The Problem** Everything was running ok till 50thinvoice, after which the system suddenly skipped 2 invoices and generated Invoice 52. We investigated the system state and found that system was not tampered externally and we also inferred that nobody accessed database from workbench. This is a major issue since it also has legal ramifications.

I have gone through several research and pinpointed to following solutions

1.Lock the entire table during transaction and release it after complete.Here my concern is what happens if server crashes/internet connection gets disconnected before the release of the lock

```
  using (Entities entities = new Entities())
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
  {
      //Lock the table during this transaction
       entities.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 KeyColumn FROM     MyTable WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)");

      //Do your work with the locked table here...

      //Complete the scope here to commit, otherwise it will rollback
      //The table lock will be released after we exit the TransactionScope block
      scope.Complete();
  }
```

2.Use storedprocedure for generating the invoicenumber and the procedure will be some thing like this

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT number FROM invoice_numbers WHERE name='main' FOR UPDATE;

assign the number to the invoice and set its status to finalized;

UPDATE invoice_numbers SET number = number + 1 WHERE name='main';
COMMIT;
```

If anyone could help me out in choosing which one could be right solution it will be of great help

Comment: Both of your solutions are poor if you have more than one concurrent user of the system. Only one person can get a invoice at once! Instead of getting the next number then building the invoice then saving the invoice instead build the invoice without a invoice number and save it, during the save calculate the next number in a transaction and assign it to the invoice. You can then read back the saved invoice to find the assigned number.

Comment: Also, if you *are* using server 2012 like your tags say you may want to look into [sequence numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878058.aspx), they are pretty much perfict for this kind of job and would replace the `invoice_numbers` table in your 2nd example.

Comment: @Scott I think you are mentioning about using triggers on insert of invoice.If not a small example will be helpful

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sequences are not consecutive, in other words they can contain gaps.